# How do i install Maria DB Server on a offline Centos VM?

Tags: linux, bash, centos, software-installation

I have a VM running CentOS 7 and need to install Maria DB server on it but i cannot use yum install or any other online based installation because the VM has no internet connection. How do i install MariaDB on a offline system with all the dependencies? Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to download the `rpm`-packages for Maria DB and its depedencies.

Transfer the files to the VM and install via (e.g.):

```
rpm -i mariadb-1.4.3.rpm
```

For showing the dependcies of an `rpm`-file use:

```
rpm -qpR mariadb-1.4.3.rpm
```

But the installation will also just show missing dependencies when you run it.

Comment: Okay, makes sense. But in my MariaDB Folder are like 20+ .rpm files. Do i have to check dependencies for all of them?

Comment: What are those rpm-files? Different versions from the repository? Then only for the version you want to install. The anoying part will be checking the dependencies recursively. There are AFAIK no simple tools available fpr zypper.

Answer (score 0):

After getting dependent packages you can install MariaDB via command:

```
yum localinstall mariadb... <other packages>
```

Using `rpm` may broke the packages database and invoke warning/error

Comment: If i try to run yum localinstall it gives me an error that this folder is not a .rpm file. Where do i find a .rpm-File version of MariaDB?

Comment: @yannis, https://mariadb.com/kb/en/rpm/ for example.